# Type Cast char_array to unsigned int in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

If i have a char array of 4 bytes in size and i try to cast him into a unsigned int(4 bytes too), the compiler give me an error `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast] no_pointer = (unsigned int) char_array;` Why give me this error if both variables have 4 bytes in size?

Code:

```
char char_array[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
unsigned int no_pointer;
no_pointer = (unsigned int) char_array;
```

Comment: A pointer is not the same as the contents. If you’re running on a 64bit system the pointer is 8 bytes even. You need to actually cast the pointer type and then dereference it to get the value

Comment: Since this doesn't make any sense to begin with, you could as well just use fancy magic numbers. `puts( (void*)&(uint64_t){1684234849} );` Please do hand in that exact solution to whatever teacher that gave you the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assing arrays by value because they get converted to address to first element. Your code is equivalent to:

```
no_pointer = (unsigned int) &char_array[0];
```

Use `memcpy` instead:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof no_pointer == sizeof char_array, "Size mismatch"); // Extra safety check to make sure that size match
memcpy(&no_pointer, char_array, sizeof no_pointer);
```

But please keep in mind that byte order is dependent on endianness when using this approach.

Answer (score -2):

the variable 'char_array' is a pointer to a memory zone (containing 4 bytes: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

so the value itself of char_array is not abcd but 0x[memory addr].

If your cast with (unsigned int), the value of your no_pointer will be 0x[memory addr]

So two solutions:
if you want a unsigned int pointer to abcd then you need:

```
unsigned int *no_pointer;
no_pointer = (unsigned int *)char_array
```

If you want the value abcd directly in the integer variable you need to dereference the pointer:

```
unsigned int no_pointer;
no_pointer = *(unsigned int *)char_array;
```

Comment: `*(unsigned int *)char_array` is strict aliasing violation. It also comes with possible alignment issues. Do not do that.